# Get user uid from name (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7

I can't figure out how to get an user's UID knowing the user's name.

The user's name will be entered by a variable. I just need to pick up the UID in another variable.

I've found this code, which would be perfect, but it doesn't work on Drupal 7:

```
$account = user_load(array('name' => check_plain($name)));
```

Can anybody help me?
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$user = user_load_by_name($username);
$user_id = $user->uid;
```

or you can use

```
function get_uid($username)
{    
    // Function that returns the uid based on the username given
    $user = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE name=':username'", array(":username" => $username)));

    return $user->uid;
}
```

Comment: `$user = user_load_by_name($username);
$user_id = $user->uid;`  

This worked like a charm! Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to look up the user is to use the `entity_load('user');`. Here is an example how to do it:

```
// Add the user you want to find here
$user_to_lookup = 'test';

$users = entity_load('user');


$found_user = null;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user->name == $user_to_lookup ) {
        $found_user = $user;
    }
}
```

The user object is stored in `$found_user` now. Note that its an stdClass so you need to use the arrow notation to access the properties. For example to access mail write `$found_user->mail`.